# mac user specific compilation/installation path

Tags: macos, compilation, directory

I'm wanting to compile MySQL into a user-specific directory on my Mac. I know how to compile it and everything, it's just the directory selection I'm looking for. The question starts at:

Is /usr/local user specific? If I installed it into there while on an active user Bob, will Joe be able to see and access it, or only Bob?

I suspect that's not the case. If it is though, then great! If it's not, then where would be the best place to compile and install stuff such that I can have that control over which users can see and access it?

Keep in mind these are for more complicated stuff like compiling MySQL so I don't want them in some generic applications folder (which is why /usr/local would be great if it had this user specific-ness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local` is system specific... so yes Bob would be able to use it. U usually keep a dir stucture uner my user home so:

```
/Users/username/
  lib/
  bin/
  etc/
```

You could install it there. That said you could just modify the user and group settings for the execute permission to a group only you and the system belong to. Im actually thinking that would be the better way to go here since having it in your home dir might make for more hurdles since youll probably want to run the mysql server as a daemon.